# VBA: Create an in memory bitmap to display as icon on commandbarbutton

Tags: vba, bitmap, ms-project

In VBA I've created a custom commmandbar with buttons that allow me to set the background color of a selection of lines in my MS Project planning.

Instead of using text captions, I'd like to display 16x16 bitmap icons with the appropriate color on each button. I can load these bitmaps from the hard disk, but would like to create them in VBA.

Is this possible? There is no bitmap or drawing class in VBA afaik after my extensive research.

What it is now:

[image]

What it should become (manually done):

[image]

Code:

```
'1 red
'2 yellow
'3 green
'4 blue
'5 dark blue
'6 fushia
'7 white

Sub createcolorbar()

    Dim cbar As CommandBar
    Dim cctrl As CommandBarButton

    On Error Resume Next
    CommandBars("Colors").Delete

    Set cbar = CommandBars.Add("Colors")
    cbar.Visible = True
    cbar.Position = msoBarTop

    With cbar
    'white
        Set ctrl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
        With ctrl
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Caption = "White"
            .State = msoButtonUp
            .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption 'change for icon
            .OnAction = "Macro ""color_white"""
            '.FaceId = 59 'Smiley
            .Picture = stdole.StdFunctions.LoadPicture("c:\Temp\a.bmp")
        End With
         ' red
        Set ctrl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
        With ctrl
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Caption = "Red"
            .State = msoButtonUp
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "Macro ""color_red"""
        End With
        'yellow
        Set ctrl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
        With ctrl
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Caption = "Yellow"
            .State = msoButtonUp
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "Macro ""color_yellow"""
        End With
        'green
        Set ctrl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
        With ctrl
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Caption = "Green"
            .State = msoButtonUp
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "Macro ""color_green"""
        End With
        'blue
        Set ctrl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
        With ctrl
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Caption = "Blue"
            .State = msoButtonUp
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "Macro ""color_blue"""
        End With
        'Darkblue
        Set ctrl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
        With ctrl
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Caption = "Darkblue"
            .State = msoButtonUp
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "Macro ""color_darkblue"""
        End With
        'fushia
        Set ctrl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
        With ctrl
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Caption = "Fushia"
            .State = msoButtonUp
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "Macro ""color_fushia"""
        End With
    End With
    Set ctrl = Nothing

End Sub

Sub color_x(x)
    Set ts = ActiveSelection.Tasks
    For Each tsk In ts
        FontEx CellColor:=x
    Next tsk
End Sub

Sub color_red()
    Call color_x(1)
End Sub

Sub color_yellow()
    Call color_x(2)
End Sub

Sub color_green()
    Call color_x(3)
End Sub

Sub color_blue()
    Call color_x(4)
End Sub

Sub color_darkblue()
    Call color_x(5)
End Sub

Sub color_fushia()
    Call color_x(6)
End Sub

Sub color_white()
    Call color_x(7)
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess `cctrl` is a typo in `Dim cctrl As CommandBarButton`. Also why not store the bitmap icons in a hidden worksheet and then load them on to the button?

Comment: Or hidden image controls in a userform from which you can export the image to the user's temp directory and then upload it in `.Picture`?

Comment: cctrl is indeed a typo, explicit is not on so it didn't return any errors - could you show me some sample code on how to store images hidden in a userform to the tempdir?

Comment: Chip Pearson posted how to do this as @SiddharthRout suggested: [http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PicturesOnCommandBarItems.aspx](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PicturesOnCommandBarItems.aspx)